# How to check each element in Cypress so that it does not fail when none are found

Tags: cypress

In my case I have a varying amount of elements with `someclass` class name on the pages. I need to run some validations on them for which I'm using the following command:

```
cy.get(".someclass").each(someValidation)
```

This works fine on other cases, but there might also be cases when the page we're checking contains none of `.someclass` elements. This is fine, and the tests should not fail. However, using the above command fails (after waiting for the timeout to end):

```
Timed out retrying after 20000ms: Expected to find element: .someclass, but never found it.
```

Comment: Can you add HTML of your elements

Answer (score 0):

Solved with some jQuery hacks:

```
const $els = Cypress.$('.someclass')
if ($els.length > 0) 
    cy.wrap($els).each(someValidation)
```